# Python os.path.join not working properly for network paths

Tags: python

Any ideas why this will not join properly in Python 2.6 Win?

```
import os

myPath = "\\\\192.168.1.50\\Shared"
myPath2 = "\\Folder2"
myFile = "1.txt"

print os.path.join(myPath, myPath2, myFile)
```

**Result:**

```
\Folder2\1.txt
```

**I was expecting the result to be "\\192.168.1.50\Shared\Folder2\1.txt" !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join is a convenience function, it is not too intelligent. For example, it does not verify existence of paths, etc. It just follows some formal rules.

As of your question, remove extra slash in `myPath2` definition.

```
import os

myPath = "\\\\192.168.1.50\\Shared"
myPath2 = "Folder2"
myFile = "1.txt"

print os.path.join(myPath, myPath2, myFile)
```

gives `\\192.168.1.50\Shared\Folder2\1.txt`

You will have same problem with ordinary paths:

```
import os

myPath = "C:\\Shared"
myPath2 = "\\Folder2"
myFile = "1.txt"

print os.path.join(myPath, myPath2, myFile)
```

gives `\Folder2\1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues.

I need to remove the slashes from the beginning of myPath2, otherwise it will be treeted as absolute path and myPath will be ignored!

```
import os

myPath = "\\\\192.168.1.50\\Shared"
myPath2 = "Folder2"
myFile = "1.txt"

print os.path.join(myPath, myPath2, myFile)
```

**Result:**

```
\\192.168.1.50\Shared\Folder2\1.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it does not support this, you can use it as normal:

```
print myPath + myPath2 + myFile
```

Comment: Ok, I got it now, documentation explains it:
If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues.

Comment: -1 Your approach yields a **wrong** result for OP's example and countless other real-world cases, whereas `os.path.join` is pretty much always correct (though it sometimes disagrees with the naive view on paths). Don't be so quick to dismiss a great tool because someone's using it wrongly.